# Will the Angular Ivy view engine have a public API?

Tags: angular, angular-ivy, angular9

An angular app I'm currently working on has several places where component templates must be dynamically created, for example to support differences in translation word order in bound content. Currently, this requires hauling around the ~500MB `@angular/compiler` package.

From what I can tell, the new Ivy view engine has the potential to solve this without all that bloat. I see that `@angular/core` now exposes all of the methods for incremental DOM interaction, such as `ɵɵdefineComponent`, `ɵɵelementStart` and `ɵɵelementEnd`. However, I am concerned that the usage of the funky *theta* (ɵ) character in there is implying an internal API, and I see no documentation for it. Is this intended for public consumption? Or alternatively, will there be some kind of friendly builder API exposed that wraps that?